# Brakes smell, car pedal hard, light smoke, slows down during gear shift

Tags: honda, brakes, civic

3 weeks ago I bought a car from a private dealer. When I tested it out, the car was completely fine. Not to long ago after, I noticed that my back tail lights were on and figured out it was the braker bolt. I changed it and then later that day I noticed my car was acting up by my brake pedal being hard when I changed gears to go to a higher one, the car would slow down. I turned off the car and smelled the brakes and saw a light smoke. When I got to my house and left it there for a few hours, it was fine. I took it to the mechanic and he told me that when the brakes get hot they start to press down and lock on. He eventually told me to change the calipers and so we did (same). Then he said it was the brake hose, we changed it (same problem). He then changed the master cylinder (same problem). I'm so frustrated. Do you have any idea what it could be?
2005 honda civic Lx

Comment: Please clean up the spelling and grammar to make this more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is meant by "*braker bolt*"?

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop ... beat you to the punch.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks all I I had time for was drive my modding... You earned him an upvote too!

Comment: Foot rested on brake pedal while driving? I know it's a long shot, but just in case...

Comment: Please tell us:  What was done to fix this situation? and tell us:  What is a Breaker Bolt?

Answer (score 1):

As you've already changed the brake calipers, hoses, and master cylinder, Im sure you've checked your brake fluid and have let out any air in the system. Another issue this could be caused by is your brake pedal.

In some Civics the entire pedal mechanism can be bought but I've seen cases where the spring within the brake pedal becomes loose, resulting in the brake pedal not fully retracting. This is sometimes called the "Return Spring".

This is where I would go next and have checked. Its been a cause to other issues I've faced too and it ended up just being a loose spring which needed changing.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom you mentioned leads me to believe that you have a bad Power Brake Booster.

Comment: Sam, we want to help you succeed on this SE site. I will ask you once again: please flesh out your answers. Tell the OP *why* it's the Power Brake Booster. Tell them how they can better diagnose it as such. One line answers don't get much attention around here (unless it's to downvote them). Thanks.